# I'm implementing printf function in C/Linux

Tags: c, linux, printf

Program:

```
 #ifndef PRINTF_H
 #define PRINTF_H
 #include "my_put_char.h"

 int my_printf(char *str, ...);

 #endif
```

This is my Header file for my function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_put_char.h"

void my_put_char(char c) 
{
     fwrite(&c, sizeof(char), 1, stdout);
}
```

This is my putchar implementation(my_put_char.c).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "printf.h"

int my_printf(char *str, ...)
{   
    if(str == NULL)
        return 0;

    int i;
    char a;

    va_list print;
    va_start(print,str);

    for(i = 0; str[i] ; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == '%')
        {
            i++;
            switch(str[i])
            {
                case 'c':
                a = va_arg(print, char);
                my_put_char(a);
                break;
            }
        }
     }
     va_end(print);
     return 0;
}
```

At last, this is a part of my printf implementation.
I'm testing with `%c` to display a character.

When I do `my_print("%c", 'd');` from `main.c` 
it compiles and displays `d`.

But when I do `my_print("%c", "hi");` , it still compiles and displays a number.

Question:

After(or before) writing `a = va_arg(print, char);` Is there a way to check whether my input is a different data type? 
I'm trying to display an error if my input is a different data type.

I'm on this subject for 2 days and couldn't find any answer.
Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: It's not possible to determine the type. Take a look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg). (It's cppreference, but doesn't matter here.) Specifically, it says "If the type of the next argument in ap (after promotions) is not compatible with T, the behavior is undefined".

Comment: @Yunnosch, thank you for editing this post!

Comment: Why does your `printf.h` header include `my_put_char.h` header?  Are users of your `printf.h` going to use what's declared in it?  Note that the format string should be `const char *fmt` (with the added `const`); C99, C11 and POSIX would have it qualified with `restrict` too (`int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);`).  Your implementation file should include your `my_put_char.h` header; it calls the function.  Your other header should (probably) not include it.

Comment: Note that when using `va_arg`, you must specify a promoted type — `int` or `unsigned int` or `double` and not anything shorter (`char`, `short`, `float`, etc).  Your line `a = va_arg(print, char);` is immediately invoking undefined behaviour.  (The verbiage from the standard §7.16.1.1 is: _…or if
type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according
to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, except…_ and the exceptions don't apply here (they relate to signed vs unsigned integers and `void *` vs `char *`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Thank you so much for your answer. So basically I need to pass a = (int)va_Arg(print, int);  since char is automatically promoted to int?

Comment: There's a reason why the GCC compilers support the `__attribute__((format(printf,1,2))` notation for checking `printf()`-like functions — it's hard to do it otherwise.

Comment: You're welcome to my comments — they're much more comment than answer.  The comment by @YiFei contains the answer I'd have to give — there isn't an easy way for you to spot the problem inside your code (though in the specific case of `%c`, you could decide that if the integer you receive is outside the applicable range of values for `char` (and/or `signed char` and/or `unsigned char`), then it is probably a bug).  That is, however, moderately hard to generalize — it couldn't be used to spot problems with integer types T where `sizeof(T) >= sizeof(int)`, or with floating point types.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I'll start with that, thank you for giving me a lead! It's been almost a month with c language and still have lots to learn! Thank you again have a great day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I do `my_print("%c", "hi");` , it still compiles and displays a number

You've got some [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108). Your `my_printf` would call `va_arg` with an argument of the bad type (expected `char` promoted to `int`, got `char*`).

To explain what is happening you should dive into implementation details (look into the assembler code, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -fverbose-asm -O -S`; study your [processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_(computing)), its [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture), its [application binary interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)). **You don't want to do that**, it could take years and is not reproducible.

Read absolutely [Lattner's blog on UB](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), right now!

Then download [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) specification [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)....

You could also, with `gcc`, use some [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes). Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)

> after writing `a = va_arg(print, char);` Is there a way to check whether my input is a different data type?

No, not really and not always. But the `format` function attribute could help. And you could also spend months customizing GCC with your own [plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) or some [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension (that is not worth your time). Be aware of the [**Halting Problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and [Rice's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) (each makes [static](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) source code [program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_analysis) so challenging). Look also into source analyzing tools like [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/).

> I'm implementing printf function

BTW studying the source code of existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) implementations of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (such as [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)) could be inspirational; they are based upon [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Basile!